# Hdfs hook dependency on snakebite throwing error

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I'm trying to use HDFS sensor in airflow. But am getting the below error

```
[2020-06-30 07:22:57,636] {dagbag.py:246} ERROR - Failed to import: /airflow/dags/test_s3_file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/airflow/airflow-staging/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 243, in process_file
m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
File "/airflow/airflow-staging/lib64/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
module = _load(spec)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/airflow/dags/test_s3_file.py", line 3, in <module>
from S3HDFSObjectSensor import S3HDFSObjectSensor
File "/airflow/plugins/S3HDFSObjectSensor.py", line 6, in <module>
from airflow.hooks.hdfs_hook import HDFSHook
File "/airflow/airflow-staging/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/hdfs_hook.py", line 24, in <module>
from snakebite.client import Client, HAClient, Namenode, AutoConfigClient
File "/airflow/airflow-staging/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakebite/client.py", line 1473
baseTime = min(time * (1L << retries), cap);
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From google, found that we will have this issue if we are using python3. Could you please let me know if there is any work around for this other than using python2.

```
from airflow.plugins.S3HDFSObjectSensor import S3HDFSObjectSensor

t1 = S3HDFSObjectSensor(
task_id='t1',
poke_interval=sensor_poke_interval,
timeout=sensor_timeout,
object_path=check_file_in_hdfs,
trigger_rule='one_failed',
dag=dag)
```

Below is my AIRFLOW_HOME directory structure

```
airflow
+-- dags
+-- plugins
    +-- S3HDFSObjectSensor.py
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It worked after installing 'pip3 install snakebite-py3'